# How to set a timer in Windows application when user is idle or not active

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I have a question in Windows Forms on setting timer when the user is idle or Inactive. I need the timer to set even on any Mouse Events. If the user makes any moment then I need to reset the timer. So this is the requirement. Here goes the code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace FormsTimerSetup.Globals
{
    public class SetApplicationTimeOut : Form
    {
        #region
        /// <summary>
        /// Private Timer Property
        /// </summary>
        private static Timer _timer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Timer Property
        /// </summary>
        public static Timer Timer
        {
            get
            {
                return _timer;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_timer != null)
                {
                    _timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
                }

                _timer = value;

                if (_timer != null)
                {
                    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public event EventHandler UserActivity;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Default/Parameterless SetApplicationTimeOut Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public SetApplicationTimeOut()
        {
            KeyPreview = true;

            FormClosed += ObservedForm_FormClosed;
            MouseMove += ObservedForm_MouseMove;
            KeyDown += ObservedForm_KeyDown;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Inherited Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected virtual void OnUserActivity(EventArgs e)
        {
            // Invoking the UserActivity delegate
            UserActivity?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void SetTimeOut()
        {
            // postpone auto-logout by 30 minutes
            _timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = (30 * 60 * 1000) // Timer set for 30 minutes
            };

            Application.Idle += Application_Idle;

            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ObservedForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            OnUserActivity(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ObservedForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            OnUserActivity(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ObservedForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            FormClosed -= ObservedForm_FormClosed;
            MouseMove -= ObservedForm_MouseMove;
            KeyDown -= ObservedForm_KeyDown;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private static void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private static void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
            MessageBox.Show("Application Terminating");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I have implemented the code but unsure whether it is the right way of doing it.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `SetTimeOut` get called in a parent form? What is the issue you're currently having?

Comment: Yes the SetTimeOut is called wherever needed. I just wanted to make sure that this code is right way of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Q: "I need the timer to set on any Mouse Events...if the user makes any movement then I need to reset the timer...Any leads would be appreciated."

A: I'll try to offer a few leads that I hope you find useful. You say you want MouseMove event to reset the timer but there's a problem: Any time a child Control has focus, it's the child that receives the mouse event and the Main Form doesn't. *This is fixable.*

The short answer: "Implement the **IMessageFilter** interface on the main window class so that the Timer is Reset when Mouse Movement is Detected." Adding a **MessageFilter** can intercept the mouse messages *before* they are sent to the focused control.

So, now I have to give you all the details so here's the long answer: It starts by adding **IMessageFilter** interface to our main Form1 like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
```

The IMessageFilter requires our class to implement just one method:

```
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            // Commit f9367d7c added at OP's request
            case WM_KEYDOWN:  
            // This makes WakeUp persist if user is typing in the textbox.
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                TimeOutState = TimeOutState.WakeUp;
                break;
        }
        return false; // Do not suppress downstream message
    }
    const int  // WinOS Messages
        WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
```

You can see that now any mouse movement sets our app's TimeOutState back to 'WakeUp'.

```
enum TimeOutState{ WakeUp, Sleeping, Warning, Exit }
```

We only need one Timer and every tick interval (here set to 5 seconds) of the timer reduces the state by one. If the mouse doesn't move, it decrements all the way down and finally exits.

Here's a 60-second [video](http://ivsoftware.com/stack-overflow/application-watch-dog-timer.mp4) of running the app for 60 seconds. You can see changes occur either every 5 seconds or when the mouse moves. If you'd like to run the sample you can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/application-watch-dog-timer.git) the latest commit from our GitHub repo.

Here are the rest of the details:

1. The MessageFilter needs to be connected. Since we need our Form to have its window handle, so we do this here and start the timer:

   ```
   protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnHandleCreated(e);
       // When our main window is ready for messages, add the MessageFilter
       Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
       // ...and start the timer for the first time.
       TimeOutState = TimeOutState.WakeUp;
   }
   ```
2. We need to instantiate the Timer, but only once in the CTor:

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _wdt = new Timer();            
       _wdt.Interval = 5000; // Use a very short time-out for this demo
       _wdt.Tick += _wdt_Tick;
   }
   Timer _wdt; // Watch-Dog Timer
   ```
3. The Timer.Tick needs to be handled:

   ```
   private void _wdt_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       // A tick reduces the TimeOutState by 1
       TimeOutState = (TimeOutState)(TimeOutState - 1);
   }
   ```
4. Finally, handle the state changes of TimeOutState and show our messages.

   ```
   TimeOutState TimeOutState
   {
       get => _timeOutState;
       set
       {
           switch (value)
           {
               case TimeOutState.WakeUp:
                   _wdt.Stop();
                   _wdt.Start();
                   break;
               case TimeOutState.Exit:
                   _wdt.Stop();
                   Application.Exit();
                   return;
           }
           if (value != _timeOutState)  // If state changes, write message
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(value.ToString(), _timeOutState.ToString());
               // In a timer callback that changes the UI, it's
               // best to post the action in the message queue.
               BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
               {
                   textBox1.AppendText(_timeOutState.ToString());
                   if (TimeOutState == TimeOutState.Warning)
                   {
                       textBox1.AppendText(
                           ": Closing in " + (_wdt.Interval / 1000).ToString() + " seconds.");
                   }
                   textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                   textBox1.Select(textBox1.TextLength, 0);
               });
           }
           _timeOutState = value;
       }
   }
   TimeOutState _timeOutState = (TimeOutState)(-1);    // Initialize to invalid state
   ```

I have used **IMessageFilter** very reliably in my own apps and I'm confident suggesting it to you as one alternative for answering your post.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works fine that being said if there is mouse movement or key stroke movement (Key Board Stroke) the timer should stop and should gets reset and the application shouldn't exit. In this case the application is getting exit no matter what the movement is. So, basically I am trying to achieve when the user is idle or inactive I should Logout him or application should get exit. Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks once again and STAY SAFE!

Comment: Oh I'm stunned and sorry to hear that! I tested the code really carefully to make sure I wouldn't waste your time on such a lengthy post as this but I'll clone it and I'll check it again.

Comment: @SandeepVemulapalli and thanks for not just immediately reaching for the downvote button. I'll definitely retest it and if my code doesn't work I'll take it down from SO just give me a few minutes.

Comment: Sure, No issues. Please take your time! Thanks!

Comment: Commit 4372df84: Fixed terrible bug that crept in at the last commit! But please look and make sure that this is the behavior you're looking for?? [MP4 60-second app run](http://ivsoftware.com/stack-overflow/application-watch-dog-timer.mp4)

Comment: @SandeepVemulapalli great question b.t.w. Having a hook like this at the application scope either for mouse events or for hotkey app commands and shortcuts is very useful. If for some reason you pull the latest commit and don't see the desired behavior, for sure let me know! Both answers posted so far use a message filter in one form or another, which makes me think both D J and I are trying to point you in a good direction.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. I just verified it is working fine for the mouse move events but unfortunately it is not detecting the Key Stroke or Key Board Events like whenever we hit any button on the key board it is not going back to Wake mode but instead going to sleep and finally exiting the application. So whenever any change either in the mouse or the keyboard then the application shouldn't exit. Please let me know your thoughts on this and take your time STAY SAFE!

Comment: Ah! Understood and I'll make that easy change (adding WM_KEYDOWN to the MessageFilter). Sometimes I get criticism if I "answer something that wasn't asked" so I tried to stick with your question about mouse movements! Since it seems like that's ok with you, I'll add it because I agree it will improve the quality of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214764/discussion-between-ivsoftware-and-sandeep-vemulapalli).

Answer (score 0):

I won't go much deeper into your code but I would like to directly approach the issue.
I think a 'roundabout' would work in this case.

For e.g. You can check whenever the mouse moves and compare it with the initial position.

Add this above Initialize Component();

```
     GlobalMouseHandler gmh = new GlobalMouseHandler();
     gmh.TheMouseMoved += new MouseMovedEvent(gmh_TheMouseMoved);
     Application.AddMessageFilter(gmh);
```

Then add this:

```
  void gmh_TheMouseMoved()
  {
     if(XY==false)
     {
        MouseX = Convert.ToInt32(Cursor.Position.X);
        MouseY = Convert.ToInt32(Cursor.Position.Y);
     }
    else
    {
        MouseX1 = Convert.ToInt32(Cursor.Position.X);
        MouseY1 = Convert.ToInt32(Cursor.Position.Y);
        XY = true;
        if(MouseX1==MouseX && MouseY1==MouseY)
        {
            if(yourTimerNameHere.Enabled==false)
            {
                yourTimerNameHere.Start();
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            yourTimerNameHere.Stop();
            yourTimerNameHere.Start();
        }
    }

  }
```

Add this outside the class of your form:

```
public delegate void MouseMovedEvent();

public class GlobalMouseHandler : IMessageFilter
{
   private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

  public event MouseMovedEvent TheMouseMoved;

  public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
  {
     if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
     {
        if (TheMouseMoved != null)
        {
           TheMouseMoved();
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

}

Next create 4 ints named MouseX = 0, MouseY = 0, MouseX1 = 0 and MouseY1 = 0 and a bool XY = false;

So actually, whenever the cursor moves, the position gets recorded and gets compared with the next. So you can check if the mouse is idle or no!

> Pls note that I haven't tested this code so feel free to revert back for any errors.